# ListBlobsFlat returning deleted blobs along with other blobs

Tags: node.js, azure, blob

I have a nodejs appservice that downloads blobs,250 at a time until 3500 blobs are downloaded (this is to limit the number of concurrent connections opened to the container) and then processes them (bulk uploading data to the database) followed by deleting them.

The appservice API is being called by another ETL tool (snaplogic) every 5 minutes. If the first run is over in say 4 mins 50 secs and the next run starts in 10 seconds, the ListBlobs flat returns deleted blob names and then the app service fails when trying to download the blobs.

I am stumped because I am specifically telling the Azure API not to list the deleted blobs. What am I doing wrong?

I know that when the blobs are deleted, azure actually just marks them for deletion and the garbage collection process eventually deletes them. But if they are already marked for deletion, then they shouldn't be sent back in the list!

```
async function getBlobNames(containerClient, maxBlobsToDownload) {
  var blobNames = [];
  var counter = 0;
  for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat({
    includeUncommitedBlobs: false,
    includeDeleted: false,
    includeSnapshots: false,
    includeVersions: false,
    includeDeletedWithVersions: false,
  })) {
    if (counter < maxBlobsToDownload) {
      blobNames.push(blob.name);
    } else {
      break;
    }
    counter++;
  }
  return blobNames;
}


async function deleteBlobs(start, end) {
  try {
    var deletePromises = [];
    const containerClient = xenialHelper.getContainerClient(
      srcConnection,
      sourceContainer
    );
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
      const blobName = blobNames[i];
      deletePromises.push(
        containerClient.deleteBlob(blobName, {
          deleteSnapshots: "include",
        })
      );
    }
    await Promise.all(deletePromises);
    console.log(`${end - start} Blobs Deleted`);
  
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Blob Delete Error");
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

async function getBlobs(start, end) {
  console.log("Getting Blobs");
  const startTime = moment();
  try {
    promises = [];
    const containerClient = xenialHelper.getContainerClient(
      srcConnection,
      sourceContainer
    );
    for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
      const blobName = blobNames[i];
      promises.push(
        downloadBlob(containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName), blobName)
      );
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log(
      `${end - start} Blobs Downloaded  ${xenialHelper.printTime(
        startTime,
        moment()
      )}`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error GetBlobs");
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

//Main Function

const maxBlobsToDownload = 1500; 

router.get("/processFiles", jsonBodyParser, async (req, res) => {

 if (req.query.maxDownloads) {
    maxBlobsToDownload = req.query.maxDownloads;
  }
try {
    const containerClient = xenialHelper.getContainerClient(
      srcConnection,
      sourceContainer
    );

    blobNames = await getBlobNames(
      containerClient,
      parseInt(maxBlobsToDownload)
    );
    console.log(blobNames.length);
    let pageSize = 250; //;
    const iterations = getIterations(blobNames, pageSize);
    let start = 0;
    let end = parseInt(pageSize);

    

    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        start = end;
        end += pageSize;
      }
      if (blobNames.length < end) {
        end = blobNames.length;
      }
      console.log(`${start} : ${end}`);
      await getBlobs(start, end);
    }
    start = 0;
    end = parseInt(pageSize);
    await processData();
    for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        start = end;
        end += pageSize;
      }
      if (blobNames.length < end) {
        end = blobNames.length;
      }
      console.log(`${start} : ${end}`);
      await deleteBlobs(start, end);
    }

    console.log("Total Time " + printTime(startTime, moment()));
    res.json({ result: "success" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.status(500).send({
      message: err,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I just ran your code (getBlobNames) and it worked perfectly fine for me. The list did not include soft-deleted blobs.

Comment: @GauravMantri I am permanently deleting the blobs...so its not even a soft delete. I am stumped. I am deleting over 250 blobs at a time.

Comment: Can you check and confirm if the blobs are actually getting deleted?

Comment: Yes, the blobs are definitely getting deleted. This is a production enviroment and for the most part it works as expected.

Comment: async isn't my speciality, but could it be that the blob listing starts executing before the delete at the end of last run is done?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the complete code so that we can see how you are using both of your functions.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: @cdub the await enforces a boundary to ensure that blobs are downloaded / processed and only then deleted. This is to ensure that if there are any errors during processing (parsing the JSON and/or Bulk Uploading the data ) then the blobs will not be deleted since an exception will be thrown before the delete code is executed.